# What are other alternatives for "Look..." or "Listen..."?

Tags: word-request

Example sentence:

> "Look/Listen," I began, "if you don't leave my apartment, I'll drag
>   you out of it."

I thought of *Listen to this/me*, but I wonder if there are other words/phrases that are shorter or more common.

Comment: Look or listen are both good options. I would go with those over "listen to this/me"

Answer (score 1):

The most common I hear is "**Now**"

- Now, if you don't leave my apartment, I'll drag you out of it.

Otherwise, "**listen**" and "**look**" both are okay.